# bash get relative path from absoulte

Tags: bash, find, relative-path, absolute-value, realpath

This line gets absolute path, i used output to pass it to rsync, but rsync wants relative path

```
find /www-data/ -type f -exec sh -c 'if ! lsof `readlink -f {}` > /dev/null; then echo `realpath {}`; fi' \; | tr '\n' '\0'
```

No idea how to feed realpath --relative-to from above output

Full code:

```
cd /www-data
find ./ -type f -exec sh -c 'if ! lsof `readlink -f {}` > /dev/null; then echo `realpath {}`; fi' \; | tr '\n' '\0' | rsync -avz --from0 --files-from=- ./ /data/map/uploads/ --dry-run
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tr '\n' '\000'` is fundamentally broken. The reason you want to push in null-terminated strings is to disambiguate between newlines which are part of a file name, and those which aren't; but if you are replacing all newlines, you are not disambiguating anything. Perhaps see also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020

Somewhat similarly, `` echo `command` ``  is just a [useless use of `echo`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo), unless you specifically want the shell to squish whitespace and expand wildcards in the output from `command`.

If I'm allowed to guess slightly at what you are actually trying to ask here, try

```
find ./ -type f -exec sh -c 'for f; do
    lsof "$(readlink -f "$f")" > /dev/null ||
    printf "%s\0" "$(realpath --relative-to /var/www-data "$f")"
  done' _ {} + |
rsync -avz --from0 --files-from=- ./ /data/mapis/clientuploads/ --dry-run
```

The crucial change is really to have `find` pass in the file names as arguments to `sh -c '...'` rather than try to replace `{}` smack dab in the middle of a string which may or may not require quoting.

Using `-exec ... {} +` with a `+` at the end should improve efficiency somewhat, at the very minor cost of adding a `for` loop to the embedded `sh` script.